# unhide usb files batch commands

Tags: windows, batch-file

I on windows 8.1.  I get USB with hidden file/folders.  To unhide them I use attrib command .  I want to run the commands by simply inserting the USB.  Pl help.

```
echo off
echo Please have patience!!!  Wait or Minimise the window!!!

rem c:\script\unhide.bat 
@echo off

for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 " %%i in (`wmic logicaldisk get caption^,description^,drivetype 2^>NUL`) do (

if %%l equ 2 (
echo %%i is a USB drive.
        )
        )
Pause
```

Here I got the drive letter H.  I am unable to use drive letter and use the following commands in USB.   How can is I run below commands in USB.  I mean Change Drive, run attrib command in USB, delete unwanted files from USB and see USB's contents.

```
cd\
attrib -s -h -r /s /d
del *.lnk
del thumbs.db
del desktop.ini
del autorun.inf
echo Your Folders has been recovered!!!  Check your folders and files
dir
pause
exit
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/794523/autorun-inf-in-windows-8-8-1-for-usb-drives

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switch to flash drive letter automatically in batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722459/switch-to-flash-drive-letter-automatically-in-batch-file)

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions
echo Please have patience!!!  Wait or Minimise the window!!!
rem c:\script\unhide.bat 
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1-3" %%i in ('
  wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=2" get caption^,drivetype^,SystemName
  ') do (
  if "%%j"=="2" (
    echo "%%i" is a USB drive ^(DriveType=%%j^).
    pushd "%%i\"
      SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
        echo current folder !CD!
      ENDLOCAL
      echo attrib -H -S -T /S /D /L >NUL 2>&1
      echo del *.lnk       2>NUL
      echo del thumbs.db   2>NUL
      echo del desktop.ini 2>NUL
      echo del autorun.inf 2>NUL
      echo Your Folders has been recovered!!!  Check your folders and files
      dir
      pause
    popd
  )
)
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof
```

Note:

- `wmic` command changed as follows:

  - `where` clause;
  - `description` omitted as this property vary in word number and therefore breaks the tokenization;
  - always non-empty property `SystemName` appended to pass over the ending *carriage return* in the line returned: `wmic` behaviour = each output line ends with `0x0D0D0A` (`<CR><CR><LF>`) instead of common `0x0D0A` (`<CR><LF>`). For another (general) approach see Dave Benham's [*`WMIC` and `FOR /F`: A fix for the trailing `<CR>` problem*](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266);
- `for /F` loop adapted according to altered `wmic` command (and `skip=1`);
- operational `attrib -H -S -T /S /D /L` is merely `echo`ed for debugging purposes; remove `echo` no sooner than debugged (the same for all `del` commands);
- used `pushd` - `popd` pair: [`PUSHD` changes the current directory/folder and stores the previous folder/path for use by the `POPD` command](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html);
- folder `System Volume Information` should keep attributes `System` & `Hidden` if present.